# A logcat error on Android EditText

Tags: android

This is my code. I would like to save my strings into the shared preference.

```
private String sla;
private String b;
private String c;
//EditText aa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
EditText aa2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
EditText aa3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences ("PREF_DEMO", 0);

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.setup);

         RadioGroup rdg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.ragp);

         rdg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, final int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case R.id.radio0:
                            sla = "au";
                            Toast.makeText(group.getContext(), "Auto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case R.id.radio1:
                             sla = "ma";
                             Toast.makeText(group.getContext(), "Manual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }
                };
            });
         final Button set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nn);
         set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
                // a=aa.getText().toString();
                 b=aa2.getText().toString();
                 c=aa3.getText().toString();
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                 editor.putString("sp", b);
                 editor.putString("tp", c);
                 editor.putString("op", sla);
                 editor.commit();
                 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         });
```

So, I got an exception from the logcat telling error on line "EditText aa3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);"
There is no parsing error in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after setContentView(R.layout.main) add this line Because before cant get refrence from layout xml file

```
  EditText aa2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2); 
  EditText aa3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
```

add like....

```
  EditText aa2;
  EditText aa3;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.setup);

         aa2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
         aa3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
```

Comment: Thank you. And eclipse asks me to add a final modifier to the definition as i uses it in another sub-class